# Applying progress bar library with logger library in nodejs

Tags: node.js, progress-bar

I want to integrate 'cli-progress' with 'pino logger' to create something like this
which the progress bar is consistent in its position

```
[=======================] 100%
log1
log2
log3
...
```

but I get this instead which the bar will be jammed up with logs

```
[===                    ] 10%
log1
log2
[==========             ] 30%
log3
...
[=======================] 100%
```

I wonder if I can achieve something like this which I can separate two write streams to the terminal

such as

```
[ writes for bar to be consistently on top ]
[ writes for logs will take the rest of the space]
```

As I know that it is impossible for me to replace "pino", is there a way I can work around with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could even use "vanilla" JS (in the sense of "no-package"), given you use Node >= 17.

The [Readline interface](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html#rlline) might be just what you need.

**Note that the Promises API (which allows to move the cursor) is still experimental, I wouldn't use that for production tools**

A small example crafted on the fly:

```
import * as readline from 'node:readline/promises';
import { stdin as input, stdout as output } from 'node:process';

const testScript = () => {
  // creates a normal interface
  const rl = readline.createInterface({ input, output });
  // creates a Promise-based interface with the same stdout
  const rlProm = new readline.Readline(output);
  // writing to stdout
  // PLEASE NOTE THAT YOU NEED TO USE \n, OTHERWISE THE STREAM IS NOT FLUSHED
  rl.write('this is a simple test\n');
  // moves the cursor 3 lines below the current position
  rlProm.moveCursor(0, 3);
  // commit "commits" the changes made to rlProm
  rlProm.commit();
  // writing to stdout
  rl.write('still a test\n');
  // moving to the third line of stdout
  rlProm.cursorTo(0, 3);
  // clearing the line
  rlProm.clearLine(0);
  // commiting changes to stdout
  rlProm.commit();
  // now that the line has been cleared, we can re-write on it
  rl.write('this line has been replaced\n');
  // moving again to the end of the script, meaning you have to keep track of what you're doing
  rlProm.cursorTo(0, 8);
  rlProm.commit();

  // finally, closing stdout stream
  rl.close();
};

testScript();
```

You could take advantage of the `clearLine` function to consistently rewrite your loading bar, giving the illusion that two streams are being written at the same time.

Now surely you can achieve that with less code with a package, but since I've never done it in JS, only in C with `curses` library, I'm not aware of any.

---

To answer specifically to question, which is about `pino` package, I don't think you can since I did not see any way of moving the cursor in their [API docs](https://github.com/pinojs/pino/blob/master/docs/api.md).